# Anonymous view while developing without quit maintenance mode

Tags: 7, maintenance-mode

I have a live website with 200 active users per hour, I put the site in maintenance mode for make some changes. You know the admin view is pretty different than the anonymous view of my website or other user roles views.

I need to know how to see how the anonymous and other roles will see my website after the changes I did "for see if everything is ok". I know you are going to answer "use local enviroment and then use backup and migrate" well I already use it but if preffer to ensure that everything is ok in the live site before take off the maintenance mode.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the [Maintenance Exempt](https://www.drupal.org/project/maintenance_exempt) module was built for. From the project description:

> This D7+ module allows specific people to perform the necessary testing on the site with all role combinations without opening the site up to all of your visitors.
>
> Exemptions can be added by:
>
> - Specifying a list of IP addresses (individually or by CIDR notation)
> - Specifying a query string variable

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you did not know that module and I was looking for something all this time !